# Access preference category layout view from Fragment

Tags: android, preferencefragment

I have a preference category with a layout like below

```
  <android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
        ------------- 
        <android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceCategory
                android:layout="@layout/test" />
        </android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceScreen>
```

The layout is like below

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:background="@color/green">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/version_textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/space_divider"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:text="Version: 7 / Build 7.1.001"
        android:textColor="@color/steel"
        android:textSize="11sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

How can I access "version_textView" in my Fragment.I tried

getView().findViewById(R.id.version_textview) &

```
     @Override
        public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
           view.findViewById(R.id.version_textview) 
        }
```

But both of them don't seem to work